# keep playing andorid media player when app killed and restart service

Tags: android, service, android-mediaplayer

My program is a music player and my Android Media Player runs on the service. The problem here is that when killed my app, the service is restarted and my player starts to work from the beginning.

```
public class AudioPlayerService extends Service implementsMediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {

    private String url = "https://www.dev2qa.com/demo/media/test.mp3";
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;
    private String TAG = "AudioPlayerService";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG,"onCreate");

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);

        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);

        mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
            }
        });
        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                return false;
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        return START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY;
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mediaPlayer.start();

    }
}
```

My program is a music player and my Android Media Player runs on the service. The problem here is that when killed my app, the service is restarted and my player starts to work from the beginning.

Comment: What behaviour are you trying to achieve? I think users will be in many cases a little embarrassed if a player starts playing again a random amount of time after it was killed. The service docs recommend using START_STICKY for media players: "This mode makes sense for things that will be explicitly started and stopped to run for arbitrary periods of time, such as a service performing background music playback". But I know a lot of developers disagree with this advice and there is a bug raised to change the docs. Personally, I wouldn't restart the player because I think it is inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If the User manually kills the App using the appropriate button in "Android Settings --> Apps --> your_app" page all its Activities, Threads and Services are killed because this is the User decision. Those killed things remain stopped in this case.

Only when the Service is killed by the System (to recover memory resources during LowMemory situation) the Service is automatically restarted if the STICKY flag is used (as you done).

It's not a good pratice to restart a Service that the User CHOOSED to kill, but you can do it using this: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms (by creating an alarm every few seconds ahead in the time during the play execution)

Yes the player will starts again from the beginning when the Service is restarted if you don't manage this situation. So I think you have to save the current position somewhere and read it when the Service is restarted by the System or by the SchedulingAlarms of my previous link.